# Line of spikes overlap text on Kitty terminal emulator

Tags: debian, bspwm, kitty

When I run kitty terminal emulator, a line of black spikes overlaps the text in each line.
I'm running a VM with Debian 12, bspwm, picom with default configuration. I've got no idea what can be happening, but I'm pretty sure is something to do with kitty.
Any idea where to start?

[image]
[image]

Comment: In terms of "pretty sure" - have you tried e.g. "xterm" or "rxvt"? Do they behave differently?

Comment: I tried xfce4-terminal, and it does not present this issue, that's why I think it could be the kitty

Answer (score 1):

I'd agree, this looks like a bug in kitty. You'd start by looking for, and if not finding one, filing a big report on kitty's bug tracker. These are both the folks who knows best where that might come from, and how to fix it.

https://github.com/kovidgoyal/kitty/issues

In the meantime, I realize you need a replacement terminal emulator, until you find a solution or a fix. Try alacritty, it's idea-wise what I'd describe closest to kitty.